# Symfony3 extends AppKernel

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, symfony-3.4

I am recently working on a project where i build my own Bundle inside the vendor. This is working out great. I also managed to add my config dependencies and other bundle dependencies.

**My problem is:**

How can i extend the Kernel inside `app/AppKernel` with my own Kernel.
The Kernel i want to use is inside the vendor (Inside the Bundle i have created).

**What i want to accomplish is:**

My bundle is "connected" with several domains (one Symfony installation for multiple projects). There will be a lot of updates in the future, where i might add new Bundle dependencies. I don't want to add them to all my projects one by one.

**What i have tried**

I have tried setting up `symfony-bundles/bundle-dependency` and i've followed this issue [Bundles and Dependencies](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/608) but it seems like you still have to edit the main `AppKernel` afterwards.

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box solution that will automatically add bundles installed by Composer to `AppKernel`. But if your bundle dependencies are always specified by a single package, you could try something like this:

- Have a single designated class with a method that returns bundles that you always want to include, for example:

  ```
  class MyKernelExtension
  {
      public static function getBundles()
      {
          return [
              new MyBundle(),
              new MyOtherBundle,
              // ...
          ];
      }
  }
  ```
- Use this method in `AppKernel::registerBundles()`:

  ```
  class AppKernel extends Kernel
  {
      public function registerBundles()
      {
          $bundles = [
              new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
              // ...
          ];

          $bundles = array_merge($bundles, MyKernelExtension::getBundles());

          return $bundles;
      }
  }
  ```

You only have to add one line to `AppKernel`, and you never have to change it. Then every time you change `MyKernelExtension` in your Composer-installable package, you only update it, and the bundles will be registered.

I'm not aware of any other solutions, however this one seems simple enough.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it sounds like a good solution. My actual goal was to not add anything in the main AppKernel. But if there isn't a other way around that, then this should also work for me. Thanks !

Comment: You could also try having the entire Kernel class inside your package, and using that in `app.php` instead of the one from `app/AppKernel.php`. But eventually you'd have to install a bundle only for a project, and it might become messy when you start changing your installable Kernel for the needs of a single project. Eventually, there's only one `registerBundles()` method that will be used, and as far as I know, there's no way around it.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added your example above and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Where should I store MyKernelExtension class?

Comment: Anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you did not start the development of the bundle rightly. It is a bad idea copy your bundle to vendor folder. It would be proper to use native dependencies like a Packagist or other related things. The right way for installing bundle must be one command like a  `composer req yourBundle` and add one line to your `AppKernel::registerBundles()` described earlier. This will save you trouble transferring updates to other instances and you will only have enough `composer update` command on each project.

Please look these links, it might help.

[Creating your very own Composer Package](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package)

[Creating your first Composer/Packagist package](https://blog.jgrossi.com//2013/creating-your-first-composer-packagist-package)